# EverNote Api for iphone

Tags: iphone, evernote

Hi I am using Evernote Api for iphone. I downloaded Api from developers site of evernote. But I dont know how to use it...Any one know about this or have any links or examples to understand this?

Comment: Have you tried reading the developer documentation available on Evernotes website?

Comment: yes.There are class file only no example code..I include cocoa folder in my project.But unable to understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding iOS sample code is a top priority. In the meantime, please have a look at http://digitalpericope.net/?p=27, which might help you get started.

Comment: I am using this link,but after providing username and password app is crashing *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'EDAMUserException', reason: 'unknown'

Comment: That code doesn't do any exception handling, you'll have to add that yourself. What you're seeing is that authentication to our web service is failing. The most common causes of this are that you're not using an active API key (consumer key and consumer secret) or you're using an incorrect username and password. Make sure that you're using the username and password of an account that you created on our sandbox service, not the production service.

Comment: let me tell.First I have to create sandbox account then register app for API key for that same account?

Comment: When I added Edam folder I am getting lots of error in 
#import <TProtocol.h>
#import <TApplicationException.h>
#import <TProtocolUtil.h>
#import <TProcessor.h>  No such file or directory .. I changed this all line like #import "TApplicationeException.h" then not getting this error.but app is crashing

Comment: I have solved the issue.If I use like [userStore authenticate:@"widevision" :textField.text:@"widevision" : @"821e11c44fbe9d3a"];  This is not showing exception,,and created note. But if i pass [userStore authenticate:username :password: consumerkey : consumer secret] It is not working,I dont know why this is happening.

Comment: Now I am adding image with node,It is posting image with note..But showing in only list of note as thumbnail image.Not showing in its details

Comment: A few things: (1) API keys and user accounts are not related. Your API key is only active on our sandbox, so when you authenticate, you need to do so using an account on the sandbox server. (2) You shouldn't share your API key publicly. (3) I can't tell from your code what you changed; the function requires you to pass a username, password, consumer key, and consumer secret. If all four values are valid, the function will succeed.

Comment: We've now got iOS sample code in our SDK, which you can download from http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/

Comment: see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908877/can-i-send-current-location-to-evernote-with-evernote-api