# Can I send Current location to evernote With Evernote API

Tags: iphone, evernote

I am using Evernote Api to send notes with audio and images .

I want to ask Can I send My current location with note using API.

I want  just like Evernote App in iphone.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply add the latitude and longitude to a new [NoteAttributes](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/Types.html#Struct_NoteAttributes), then add the NoteAttributes to the Note.attributes field before you call createNote().